# Selenium VBA XPath with variable predicate loop

Tags: vba, selenium, loops, xpath, predicate

I am hoping for some help with syntax in Selenium VBA.

I am trying to scrape some table date using a variable predicate 'r' to specify the row like this but it does not work.

The code does work when an integer value is put in in place of a predicate 'r' [I think predicate is the right word from looking around] so I know that the expression is finding the right thing.

```
For r = 2 To 4

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Cells(r, 1).Value = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ucOrdersList_dgOrders']/tbody/tr[r]/td[2]").Text

Next r
```

It seems as though it should be possible.  I found this but am not sure what language it is or how to translate it into Selenium VBA:

```
for (int i =1;i<rows.size();i++)
            {    
                max= wd.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[" + (i+1)+ "]/td[4]")).getText();
```

So in essence how do I do the
`tr[" + (i+1)+ "]` bit in Selenium VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ampersand `&` to join strings in VB  try `"tr[" & (i+1) &"]"`  - i should write an answer for it :-)

Comment: Also - `predicate` pretty much means to evaluate true or false based on the input. I think you want `parameterise` here - that means to replace with a dynamic value. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Thanks RichEdwards.  For anyone else - the spaces of the " and & with respect to the variable are crucial but might be corrected by your code editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your loop:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Cells(r, 1).Value = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ucOrdersList_dgOrders']/tbody/tr[" & r & "]/td[2]").Text
```

Use ampersand & to join strings.

This is the key bit: `"...tr[" & r & "]/td..."`

More info on joining strings in vb [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vb-net-language/0596000928/apcs03.html)

For the + operator, they state:

> Although in principle the + sign is identical to the & concatenation
> operator, it also doubles as the addition operator. Hence, as
> Microsoft states:
>
> When you use the + operator, you may not be able to determine whether
> addition or string concatenation will occur. Use the & operator for
> concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and provide self-documenting
> code.